# up-to-date development tools

Tags: mysql, xampp, desktop

I retired as a web developer 10 years ago. Now I'm looking to do some personal development work again and I'm at a bit of a loss to know what technologies to start with. 10 years back I was quite highly skilled with LAMP stack development including server administration. My admin and development skills were mainly with:
Linux (CentOS), RedHat, Unix (Solaris)
CPanel and WHM
PHP5 using strongly object-oriented code and my own MVC framework (more than 10 years development starting before CakePHP etc were mainstream)
JavaScript including JQuery
MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle
Some XML
Other stuff like that, of that vintage.

My preferred development environment back then was Windows 7 with XAMPP and Dreamweaver CS as a text editor, although other text editors like UltraEdit were fine too. I did lots of development on Linux using VIM but it wasn't my preference for efficiency.

Now I find myself really out of touch. It seems that MySQL has become proprietary. I hear some things about something called MariaDB. WordPress seems to be everywhere. So, my question is: starting over, preferring to stick with a production environment of Linux, PHP, an open-source database and Javascript and a development environment of Windows desktop running a LAMP emulator locally, what are the best choices to be very flexible for complete custom development, but also including developing for WordPress?

Comment: I don't think this is appropriate here as it is opinion based.  MariaDB is a drop-in replacement (fork) for MySQL - just use that.  If you are starting off new, use PHP 8.  As Wordpress is just a (frankly horrible, but very convenient and ubiquitous) framework using PHP  + MYSQL code it should port easily between a LAMP and WAMP stack.   Most of your learning will likely come from working out how the Wordpress framework fits together, and if you are writing modules or themes for it how to make those work in the framework (you can get very far within Wordpress without touching PHP or MySQL)